# Can't find AD Groups in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

I am setting up SharePoint 2016 on-premises.  I have the User Profile Service running and have correctly configured the User Profile Service Application.  I am now trying to set up navigation on our main site using Audiences.  When I add a link and attempt to use an Active Directory group as an audience, I can't find any of the groups.  I have also attempted to create an audience with a memberOf rule, but cannot find any AD groups like this either.  However, if I go to People and Groups and Add a User to a group, I can successfully find all my AD groups.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Are you importing groups via the UPSA? You need to make sure the OU they're contained in is synchronized.

Comment: Yes I am and I double checked to make sure I selected the correct OU.  When selecting an OU, though, does it pull in that OU and all children?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the things:

1. Did you start user profile synchronization service and add connection to sync from AD? Please go to Central Administration->Manager services on server/Manage web applications->User profile service application->configure synchronization connections.
2. In the Select Audience dialog, select “Distribution/Security Groups” category and check.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've set the User Profile service up and gone over the configuration several times.

Comment: And I've also tried select Distribution/Security groups in that dialog and I don't get any results back.